# @invariant tag for public classes

Tags: java, ibm-rad

We use IBM Rational Software Architect for Websphere Software. We ran the code analyzer and it is giving the bellow warning.

**@invariant tag for public classes is missing**

I did a google search for this and I couldn't find any useful information.
Please explain me for what perpose we have to use @invariant tag and how can we use.
It is very helpful if you provide any example.